# Create SecIdentity from Certificate

Tags: macos, ssl

How can i create a SecIdentityRef object to use with SSLSetCertificate?

I have load the server certificate an private key using SecItemImport from separate PEM files, but haven't import then into the keychain.

It's possible to create the SecIdentityRef without importing the files into the keychain?

Seems that SecIdentityCreateWithCertificate can be used when the private key is in the keychain, and that SecItemImport or SecPKCS12Import can return an SecIdentityRef when importing PKCS #12 blob.

So my preference will be to work with the PEM files, and avoid import the key into the keychain if possible.